# Humff. What am I?

Tags: riddle

I'm loud and proud

I love a good crowd

I like to repeat

I can drop a beat

I'm definitely not a parakeet

What am I?

Hint:

> Boom!

Comment: I was going with David Guetta, but I don't think this is the intended answer :).

Comment: Nice one, lol.  Sorry but take another guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> PA System, i.e. Public Address system that consists of big and loud speakers

I'm loud and proud

> It is certainly loud

I love a good crowd

> That's where it is used

I like to repeat

> You can use it for speeches

I can drop a beat

> Or to play some music

I'm definitely not a parakeet

> And it is not a parrot.

About the hint:

> The big speakers are often called **boom**boxes.

Comment: This was my intended answer, great job!

Comment: about the hint?

Comment: @lois6b pls see my edit

Comment: ohh ... i see. as it was a riddle i discarded all music-referenced things (as speakers v.v)

Answer (score 8):

Solution:

> Fireworks!

I'm loud and proud

> They make lots of noise. Apart from the lights, the noise is also fun.(sorry dogs)

I love a good crowd

> They are used in crowded events

I like to repeat

> they are usually repeated booms. Also, the echo

I can drop a beat

> Those repetitions can be arranged to make a beat

I'm definitely not a parakeet

> Obviously it's not. But maybe there are Parakeet Shapes that can be done

Hint:

> Boom, as the explotion

Comment: This is an amazing answer, glad I haven't fallen asleep.  +1 for being awsome

Comment: but is not the correct one.. v.v

Comment: The last guy actually got what I intended

Answer (score 2):

You're a

> musical drum

I'm loud and proud

> create loud music. Also proud to do so.

I love a good crowd

> Of course, it does.

I like to repeat

> repeats music

I can drop a beat

> creates beats that make people move on their feet.

I'm definitely not a parakeet

> No, they are not.

Hint:

> Boom, when hit.

Comment: a music band wouldnt be much of a riddle, would it?

Comment: Much better, but not what I was hoping for