# A cross, what am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

My cross shape is odd

For I have no symmetry

My head is like a rod

Under it, a wrecking ball leashed to me

And when I clap, my head does a nod

What am I?

Hint:

> Cups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a

> Kendama?

My cross shape is odd, For I have no symmetry

> The kendama is shaped like a cross, but the cups of the kendama are different sizes.

My head is like a rod, Under it, a wrecking ball leashed to me

> The head is the spike, and the ball is attached to it by a string at the center of the cross.

And when I clap, my head does a nod

> ...Not sure. When you play with a kendama, it makes a "clapping" sound when the ball goes into one of the cups? And you bob the toy up and down in order to do that?

And the hint

> Kendama is a variant of a cup-and-ball game.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like

> A crane (for construction, not a bird)

```
My cross shape is odd
For I have no symmetry
```

> A crane is an asymmetric cross shape

```
My head is like a rod  
 Under it, a wrecking ball leashed to me
```

> The long section is the active part, with tools (for example, a wrecking ball) attached to it by cables

```
And when I clap, my head does a nod
```

> Here's where it falls apart - no idea how this or the hint would link in, I'm afraid

Comment: but since this is a riddle, when you see "wrecking ball" you shouldnt be thinking about an actual wrecking ball

Comment: @lois6b It did seem unusually direct

Comment: like this one: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40314/humff-what-am-i/40316#40316 if i see "loud", "beat", etc, i dont think about speakers cause its describing, not riddling

Comment: I thought about the same thing. Didn't post because of the hint "cups".

Comment: The last on was too descriptive and I apologize for it, I have tried to mend it with this one.  This one is quite metaphorical.  Sorry this one is not a crane.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be

> A bear trap

My cross shape is odd

> when laid flat with chain and trigger outstretched a bear trap can look like a cross shape

For I have no symmetry

> the teeth are usually numbered even on one side and odd on the other

My head is like a rod

> (I think) The pressure-plate sits upon a short rod that operates a lever

Under it, a wrecking ball leashed to me

> Perhaps referring to the chain/tether?

And when I clap, my head does a nod

> The preasure pad goes down and the trap 'claps'

the Hint

> Is where I run out of ideas and think my explanations may be a bit weak...  It also throws a spanner into the works for my pendulum idea... (rod with wrecking ball that nods when it claps (like a metronome?) but those would usually be symmetrical anyway I guess...

Good riddle it seems to me.  Didn't understand the down-votes... +1